# MySql Converting to DECIMAL(8,2) not working

Tags: mysql, decimal

Trying to use MYSQL and convert a computed colmn named "FinalPrice". The formula goes something like this

```
([InitialPrice]/(100))*((100)-[PercentageOff]))
```

Both InitialPrice and PercentageOff in my DB are of datatype DECIMAL(8, 2)

Problem that I am facing I cant seem to convert the data type within the formula. Cant seem to figure out what is the problem. Im trying to get a output with the datatype of DECIMAL(8,2)

I tried this just to check and it worked,

```
 (CONVERT([int],[InitialPrice]/(100))*((100)-[PercentageOff]))
```

But this formula doesn't,

```
 (CONVERT([DECIMAL(8,2)],[InitialPrice]/(100))*((100)-[PercentageOff]))
```

The error message I am getting states "Error validating the formula for column 'FinalPrice'."

Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information, and while you're at it add information about what types `InitialPrice` and `PercentageOff` are in the DB.

Comment: That looks like MSAccess (and possibly MS SQL?) syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use `ROUND()` function, not `CAST` or `CONVERT`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff0b8/1

```
SELECT *,
ROUND( InitialPrice*((100-PercentageOff)/100),2) FinalPrice,
CAST(InitialPrice*((100-PercentageOff)/100) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) FinalPrice1
FROM table1;
```